# Now is the time. vs. The time is now

Tags: questions, writing

I need help with this:

Now is the time

vs

The time is now

For example - Now is the time to go to the store, or The time is now to go to the store.

- Which is correct?

Answer (score 3):

"[Now is the time](https://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/now-is-the-time-to-do-something#:%7E:text=Use%20this%20phrase%20to%20talk%20about%20something%20that,the%20time%20to%20invest%20in%20solar%20power%20initiatives.)" is for important events, e.g. "Now is the time to do something about climate change."

"The time is now" can also be used for important events, but the words referring to the event should come before it, e.g. "As far as doing something about climate change, the time is now."

"The time is now" can also be used simply to report the current time, e.g. "The time is now 10:25." It is a bit more formal than "It's 10:25." For example, at the beginning of an exam, the invigilator could announce to the examinees, "You have two hours for this exam; the time is now 10:25.

If you're just going to the store, neither of these phrases is appropriate. Just say, "It's time to go to the store."

Comment: You can use either for important events, with no advantage to either.

Answer (score 1):

If we say that "It's time to go to the store now," then we are making a matter-of-fact announcement of when to go to the store.

"The time is now" or "Now is the time" seems to emphasize the significance of the timing in a somewhat grandiose manner.

Comment: Agreed, Steve. You'd probably find supporting references hard to find. What about how _Now is the time to go to the store_ and _The time is now to go to the store_ sound? _The time is now_ doesn't seem to sound right with a to-infinitival clause to my ears.

Comment: Grandiose, indeed. *The time is now* is a metaphor for a big moment in the arc of time, not a pointing-to-the-clock marker of digital or analog accuracy.